# How to make an object JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models

I have an object called `Exercise` which has a lot of variables and i only wish to serialize two variables: `id` and `name` for each `Exercise`.

This is how my vars looks like:

```
{'exercises': [<Exercise: 16>, <Exercise: 1>, <Exercise: 177>, <Exercise: 163>, <Exercise: 291>, <Exercise: 209>], 'score': 16.0}
```

How do i turn this into:

```
{'exercises': [{16,"some name"}, {1,"some name"}, {177,"some name"}, {163,"some name"}, {291,"some name"}, {209,"some name"}], 'score': 16.0}
```

When i do a `json_dumps(vars(exerciseobject))` i obviously get an error `TypeError: <Exercise: 16> is not JSON serializable`

Source:

```
# Model
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.id)

# Object
class ExercisesObject:
    def __init__(self, aScore, aExercises):
        self.score = aScore
        self.exercises = aExercises # Contains an array of Exercise instances.

# Example:
firstExercise = Exercise.objects.get(pk=1)
secondExercise = Exercise.objects.get(pk=5)
aList = [firstExercise,secondExercise]
obj = ExercisesObject(23,aList)
```

Comment: What framework/orm are you using?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, i am using Django ORM.

Comment: So, perhaps [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) could help you.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, please see my updated post, im not quite sure how the serializer can help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way to do that is using [serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) native from Django.

```
from django.core import serializers


class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", Exercise.objects.all(), fields=('name'))
```

Making your custom class return JSON

```
from json import dumps

class ExercisesObject:
    def __init__(self, aScore, aExercises):
        self.score = aScore
        self.exercises = [{e.id: e.name} for e in aExercises]

    def json(self):
        return dumps({'score': self.score, 'exercises': self.exercises})
```

Comment: This example does not serialize my `exercises` list in `ExercisesObject` which contains the `Exercise` objects.

Comment: Update question with `aScore` and `aExercises` data examples. And, where come from this data?

Comment: I have added an minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide custom json encoder which is subclass of [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder):

```
class Exercise:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.name = 'soem name'


import json
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Exercise):
            return {'value': o.value, 'name': o.name}
        return super(CustomEncoder, self).default(o)

obj = {
    'exercises': [
        Exercise(16),
        Exercise(1),
        Exercise(177),
        Exercise(163),
        Exercise(291),
        Exercise(209)
    ],
    'score': 16.0
}
print(json.dumps(obj, cls=CustomEncoder, indent=4))
```

output:

```
{
    "exercises": [
        {
            "name": "some name",
            "value": 16
        },
        ...
    ],
    "score": 16.0
}
```

Comment: I am getting following error: `TypeError: <__main__.obj instance at 0x23e6cb0> is not JSON serializable`. If i change it to `print json.dumps(obj.exercises,cls=CustomEncoder,sort_keys=True, indent=4)` it works, although i wont get the `score` printed out as intended.. As i mentioned earlier i forgot to say its Django ORM, but i am using it for an utlility which means that i am constructing an object with elements retrieved by the Django-ORM.